# Java method to accept ArrayLists of different superclasses, must use Interface?

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I have a method called `findNearest` which is used to find the nearest `Object` to a point from an `ArrayList` of objects.

However I want to be able to call the method for ArrayLists of different Classes which are superclasses of
my base class `Entity`

For example `Tree` is a subclass of `Entity`, as is `Worker`. I want to be able to to `findNearest(x,y,<Arraylist of Trees>)`
and also `findNearest(x,y,<Arraylist of Workers>)`

I think I can achieve this using an Interface, but is there a simpler/cleaner way to do it?

Thanks

Duncan

Comment: Do you mean Tree is a *sub*class of Entity?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use covariance:

```
void findNearest(int x, int y, ArrayList<? extends Entity> items)
```

Note that you won't be able to add anything to the list, since you don't know what type the list is actually supposed to contain.